# Switching UIViews from a single XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

I'm having a little trouble with essentially flipping a UIView to imitate a card turning over.

As it stands, I have created two UIViews (front and rear) inside a XIB and loaded it into the storyboard as such:

```
//Initiate the view from the XIB
CustomClass *drag = [[CustomClass alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
//Add the view to the view (container) within the storyboard
[self.draggableView addSubview:drag];
```

Inside my custom class is the following:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];


     self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Draggable"
                                          owner:self
                                        options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
     return self;
}
```

This satisfactorily presents the front view...

Now I cannot for the life of me work out how to flip the view to display another UIView inside the same XIB... This UIView is available at "objectAtIndex:1".

I'm pretty certain the code I need includes:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:UIVIEW
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                    animations: ^{}];
```

Comment: What have we moved onto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If xib has many views, You should use loadNibNamed to create the view in xib file:

```
 NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BlueView" owner:nil options:nil];    

     self.blueView = views[0];

     self.yellowView = views[1];
```